# Using worker thread in electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder, worker-thread

I would like to use [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in my electron app. In my developer environment it is working, but after building the app with electron-builder, the javascript file that contains the worker thread code cannot be loaded by the Worker class.

It seems, the Worker class cannot load the js from the asar file.

[error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lefbs.png)

After I turned off the asar packaging, it's working (but using without asar packaging is not recommended so it's not an acceptable solution for me).

There is a [minimal example](https://github.com/fricci/electron_worker_thread) to reproduce the problem.

versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "electron": "7.1.2",
   "electron-builder": "22.2.0"
}
```

Did I something wrong? Is there any workaround to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I have the exact same problem ! And would like to use workers in my packaged application... In Dev mode it works too.

Comment: According to this [document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging#extra-unpacking-on-some-apis) at the moment it is impossible to start worker thread from asar file.